# Wordpress: <body class="customize-support">

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Quite simple, I want to remove customize-support class from `<body>`. I'm searching for a while now, can't find where it's been generated.

I want to embed content from one site to another using Ajax Include Script(Dynamic Drive) and CORS, so I need to replace `<body>` and its CSS with something else, otherwise it messes with site's CSS, they merge together.

When I replace `<body>` with `<abody>` it creates another `<body>`, level above, with only `"customize-support"` class.

Maybe there's another solution? Method above was the only one I could come up with.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's in your theme files?

Comment: When logged out, this class doesn't seem to be added.

Answer (score 8):

I spent a while trying to find this, and ideally solve it with overriding a hook or something, but no luck.

In wp-includes/theme.php, there's a function at the end of the file named "wp_customize_support_script", and it was introduced in WP 3.4.0.

If you look in that function, you'll see inline Javascript adding the class name. More specifically, the last line of the JS, so:

```
b[c] += ( window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-' ) + cs;
```

You could comment that out if the class really bothers you, but I'd recommend against editing WP core files. Because it's inline JS, I've yet to find a way to really alter it (*without editing core, ofc*). Hopefully a more elegant solution will turn up, but until then, I'll just use jQuery to remove the class and save my sanity.

Note that this class is only added when you are signed into the backend, and your user has the capability to edit themes.

**EDIT--**

**If you remove the admin bar on the front end, the class won't be added. So for example, in my functions.php, I have:**

```
// Removing front end admin bar because it's ugly
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This class is added by `wp-includes/admin-bar.php` (provided the user has permission to customise) with the action:

```
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wp_customize_support_script' );
```

This function adds the JavaScript which leads to the CSS class being added to the body. Removing `body_class()` from your template makes no difference, as other answers have stated.

The class is only added if the admin bar is visible, but you can remove the JS, and hence the css class using the following:

```
add_action('admin_bar_menu', function() {
    remove_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'wp_customize_support_script');
}, 50);
```

Comment: This worked for me and removed the injected JavaScript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you are logged on as administrator, this class is not present to the website visitors. If you still want to remove it you can disable the admin bar.

Answer (score -2):

May be this is due to functions.php

It contains all the run-time functions to be executed.

Search for the mentioned class in the functions.php, or something similar like page.php or single.php

According to my personal experience, there should be something like

```
<body <?php some_class(); ?>>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This isn't answer but more a rambling guess!

Answer (score -2):

I know I am a little late on here, but people might still run into this problem and these solutions are overcomplicated. Simply go into your theme and find the     body tag change it to body class="whatever"

Then in CSS make the margin 0px.

done. Your CSS overrides the other.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem at all, and changing the css margins is nothing to do with the question.